# Correlation between BSE/CJD and Brexit vote

Tags: politics, united-kingdom, brexit

This image is currently doing the rounds on social media:

[image]

The implications and associated text with it is usually around how uncanny (and amusing) the correlation is. What's the source of this data and is it actually accurate or a fake?

EDIT: Here is a better-quality picture taken [from a more recent post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44976/terrible-map-brexit-vs-bse).

[image: brexit-vs-bse-terrible-maps]

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1138/

Comment: It's pretty obviously a recolouring of the referendum map to make a joke about correlation not implying causality. The joke works because you'd expect a correlation (both BSE and Leave-voting tended to be more common in rural areas) but not the implied "mad" causality... It's obviously not a real BSE map: it depicts higher BSE in (Leave-supporting) former-industrial conurbations like those around Sunderland and Wolverhampton than in (Remain-supporting) rural farming areas like the Scottish lowlands, the Cotswolds, and Northern Irish borderlands

Comment: From the context where I first saw this the point intended was a topical humorous illustration of "correlation≠causation" not a substantive point making a real claim.

Comment: And the map doesn't look like other maps of the BSE prevalence in the UK like the one in [this paper](http://molecular-pathological-epidemiology.imedpub.com/cwd-tuberculosis-found-in-spongiformdisease-formerly-attributed-to-prions-itsimplication-towards-mad-cow-diseasescrapie-and-alzhei.php?aid=19116)

Comment: I can't make out the labels in the key. Is there a better image?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**The data is fake, the original was intended to be humorous not realistic**

The context of the original post clearly indicates that the intent was a humorous illustration of the point that correlation doesn't equal causation.

The [Snopes analysis](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/mad-cow-versus-brexit/) shows that the BSE map is a fake created by altering the referendum map. The Snopes comparison of the maps is convincing:
[image: snopes maps].

Moreover, other maps of the prevalence of BSE in the original outbreak look very different. [This paper](http://molecular-pathological-epidemiology.imedpub.com/cwd-tuberculosis-found-in-spongiformdisease-formerly-attributed-to-prions-itsimplication-towards-mad-cow-diseasescrapie-and-alzhei.php?aid=19116), for example, shows the map below (left hand map is BSE prevalence):

[image: actual prevalence of BSE in 1997]

The two maps are very different (not least in Scotland) in detail. The differences are too large for the supposed 1992 map to be realistic however redrawn.

I think we can conclude that this was never intended to be a serious point merely a faked humorous illustration.